# Doesn't heat project support -var param in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix, fragment, heat

I'm having problems using the command

```
"$(WIX)bin\heat.exe" project "$(SolutionDir)\My.project.csproj" -dr FOLDER -cg filesUP -pog:Content -pog:Satellites -gg -g1 -sf -srd -suid -var "var.SourceDir" -out "$(ProjectDir)FilesFragment.wxs"
```

the output file is ignoring this parameter ***-var "var.SourceDir"*** and using ***var.My.project.ProjectDir***

```
...
<Component Id="My.project.Content.Web.config" Directory="My.project.Content" Guid="10E9C2E0-2A35-4D6F-B12D-D66AE2E831D4">
    <File Id="My.project.Content.Web.config" Source="$(var.My.project.ProjectDir)\Web.config" />
</Component>
...
```

Visual Studio 2010 returns this error:

> Undefined preprocessor variable '$(var.My.project.ProjectDir)'.
>   C:\My.project\My.project.Installer\FilesFragment.wxs

I searched, but only found examples where **heat** is used with the parameter **dir**.

I did not find anything in the documentation that says the parameter ***-var*** is not supported by heat project.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

One solution I found is instead of using the command:

```
"$(WIX)bin\heat.exe" project "$(SolutionDir)\My.project.csproj" -dr FOLDER -cg filesUP -pog:Content -pog:Satellites -gg -g1 -sf -srd -suid -var var.SourceDir -out "$(ProjectDir)FilesFragment.wxs"
```

remove the parameter `-var var.SourceDir` and set the environment variable `My.project.ProjectDir` in its place and remove the parameter `-dr FOLDER` and set in the file **Setup.wxs** an id `My.project.Content` in its place.

This way, the command shall look like this:

```
"$(WIX)bin\heat.exe" project "$(SolutionDir)\My.project.csproj" -cg filesUP -pog:Content -pog:Satellites -gg -g1 -sf -srd -suid -out "$(ProjectDir)FilesFragment.wxs"
```

In my use case I had no problems with this solution so far.

Comment: Accept your own answer so that others know what actually helped in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this option with no problems in my project. Perhaps, the quotes are unnecessary?
Try `-var var.SourceDir` instead of `-var "var.SourceDir"`.

Another guess: you harvest a project (`heat.exe project`). It could be that this option ignores `-var` switch, and overrides it with something project related. As far as I remember, the `project` harvesting type doesn't work that well in heat and is not recommended for usage... You can try to run `heat.exe dir` instead to see if it passes the `-var` correctly.

Comment: The problem in using `heat dir` is that it captures all project files.
Even using the `-t` to filter the output of `heat dir`, It would be interesting to use the `heat project` to filter the files.
What would be the most appropriate option to filter the files of the project to generate the installer?

Comment: I don't think `heat project` works well enough to be used in production. Take a look at [this set of issues planned for WiX v4.0](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?limit=25&func=&group_id=105970&atid=642714&assignee=&status=&category=839017&artgroup=866581&keyword=&submitter=&artifact_id=0&assignee=&status=&category=839017&artgroup=866581&submitter=&keyword=project&artifact_id=0&submit=Filter), for example.

Comment: So you can either play with it to find the "not-so-buggy" scenario, or tweak the `heat dir` output the way you need...

Comment: I managed to make it work by creating a variable with the name of **My.project.ProjectDir** in place of **var.SourceDir**.
In my scenario I had no problems so far.
But thanks for the warning.
Thanks

Comment: Is there an alternative to heat project as an pre build task. Like using HeatProject in wixproj file?